# Why do the "boolean inclusive" versions of NavigableSet return a NavigableSet, and those without the "boolean inclusive" a SortedSet?

Tags: java

The title says it all... I am wondering why when I create a subset of a `NavigableSet` via e.g. `headSet(E toElement)`, I get a `SortedSet`, and with the `boolean inclusive` as an argument, i.e. `headSet(E toElement, boolean inclusive)`, I get a `NavigableSet`.

I know that `NavigableSet` extends `SortedSet`, and `SortedSet` has a method `headSet(E toElement)` that returns a `SortedSet`, but why didn't they decide to change the return type in the subinterface? Or also return a `SortedSet` with the newly added `headSet(E toElement, boolean inclusive)`, just to be consistent?

The set that is returned just differs in whether `toElement` is included or not, so I don't see why they should have different types.

Comment: Any feedback on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the boolean `inclusive` represent if the high endpoint is to be included in the returned view.

To retrieve a Set that also contains the highest ending point, the `subset` method will be called which return a `SortedSet` this is why it is the instance you get.

The method `headSet` that you call will call `subSet` in it since you specify it to be inclusive.

See [subSet documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#subSet(E,%20E))

It is logical if you think to it, that it is easier to use a sorted set if you want to deal with finding highest/lower values etc.

**Edit :** The javadoc does explain this point, thanks to @laune for pointing this out :

> Methods subSet(E, E), headSet(E), and tailSet(E) are specified to
>   return SortedSet to allow existing implementations of SortedSet to be
>   compatibly retrofitted to implement NavigableSet, but extensions and
>   implementations of this interface are encouraged to override these
>   methods to return NavigableSet.

Comment: From the Javadoc of NavigableSet: Methods subSet(E, E), headSet(E), and tailSet(E) are specified to return SortedSet to allow existing implementations of SortedSet to be compatibly retrofitted to implement NavigableSet, but extensions and implementations of this interface are encouraged to override these methods to return NavigableSet.

Comment: Great comment, I'll edit my answer to add it. Thanks.

Comment: Apart from the javadoc part of your answer, which you didn't provide but laune, I don't understand what you are trying to say. Why should it be easier to use the superclass (`SortedSet`) when the subclass inherits all its methods? This part of your answer is not true. The other stuff you wrote I didn't ask or provided in my question. The only helpful part is really the javadoc part.